# When use this code ```Form1 form = new Form1();``` something goes wrong

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to use use the code `form.mainPnl.Controls.Add(background);` where mainPnl is a panel I have added to Form1 that im just using for a base, and background is being created during debug.

```
var background = new Panel
{
Name = "background",
Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
BackColor = Color.Black,
};
```

Im working in a side class (Not sure what it's called. It's just not the base class) which means I cant use anything from the mainPnl panel without getting it from Form1 so I need to use `Form1 form = new Form1();` but whenever I use this I think it's looping and crashing the program.

Main Class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Panel mainPnl
        {
            get
            {
                return mainPanel;
            }
        }
        public TextBox textbox
        {
            get
            {
                return hey;
            }
        }

        Menu menu = new Menu();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            menu.Main();
        }

        private void Update_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Side Class:

```
class Menu
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();

        public void Main()
        {
            createObjects();
        }

        public void createObjects()
        {
            var background = new Panel
            {
                Name = "background",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                BackColor = Color.Black,
            };
            form.mainPnl.Controls.Add(background);
        }
    }
```

Thats the only code. But when I run the code, it shows an error and highlights that code and says 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown'

Comment: Nothing wrong with the posted code.  Post the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: do you have any for or while loop in program?

Comment: when using `Form1 form = new Form1();` it says this error during runtime **'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown'**

Comment: Do you have code in your constructor?  Or in the load event?  Show that.

Comment: No. Im using a void to create the panel and then only calling that void when form is loaded. Thats all

Comment: Ok the reason why I think its that code is because when I put that code directly into the void where I create the panel, nothing happens because the code cant get past the "loop".

Comment: `cant get past the "loop"`  What loop?  Where are you calling `Form1 form = new Form1();` ?

Comment: Ok I posted some code  to show you what there is.

Comment: I deleted it. But do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Your Menu class can't be making "another" Form1 class, so get rid of the `Form1 form = new Form1();` code in it.  Not sure what the point of your code is, but pass the reference of the form instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form you have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Menu menu = new Menu();
}
```

And in your `Menu` class you have:

```
class Menu
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
}
```

And when you instantiate your form, it creates a menu which instantiates a new form which creates a new menu and so on until you run out of stack space for the mutually recursive constructors.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do or what your question is other than why you're getting a stack overflow, so here you go!

Comment: But how do I get around this. I need to access things from`form1` inside of `main` and vise versa

Comment: So access them, why are you creating a new form?

Comment: I cant use voids/variables from `main` without using `Menu menu = new Menu();` and I cant use any panels/pictureboxes from  `form1` without using `Form1 form = new Form1();`

Comment: Question asked and answered.  Please mark this as answered and open a new question.

Comment: @OneWetBoy, where are you getting these (absolutely wrong) preconceived notions from? Of course you can access objects in memory, by using handles. What exactly don't you know how to do, pass handles as parameters? Store fields in a class? Call `=`? Forget all the code you wrote, it's wrong to a space, what exactly is your issue here? Not the issue with the code you wrote, but your actual issue.

Comment: My actual issue is on the form1 designer I created a panel called "mainPanel" but im not able to use the code `mainPanel.Controls.Add(background)` because mainPanel doesnt exist in the secondary class

Comment: Okay, so pass `mainPanel` to your `Menu` class, store it in a field and access it as needed. But the pattern you're using here is completely wrong, .Net already has user controls which handle all of this for you.

Comment: well I tried using `var mainPnl = (Panel)Form1.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("mainPanel", true).FirstOrDefault();` but then it shows the error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: @OneWetBoy pass a reference of the calling Menu into your Form1-Construtor.

Comment: I haven't gone to coding school. I'm 15 and self taught and its been like a month but thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Recursion! StackoverflowExeption usually happens because of recursion (in my experience)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  Menu menu = new Menu(); // Creates new Menu
}
class Menu
{
  Form1 form = new Form1(); // Creates new Form1
}
```